# Extract image URLS from JSON encoded datafeed

Tags: jquery, image, json, feed

I have limited experience with JSON, and am trying to extract image URLs from a data feed -

This is what I have for a source -

```
<HTML>
<head>

<script type="application/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{

    $.getJSON('http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=b4cac2fb1f1930eb8efce1812b69d5ab_render=json',
    function(data)
    {   

         $('#Item_URL').html(data.value.items[0].description +' URL for item photo.');

    });



})
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="Item_URL"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Of course, Item_URL shows the whole data element for the feed, which includes a ton of text that is not needed!

Here is a fragment of the JSON data

```
{
  "count": 10,
  "value": {
    "title": "Etsy Feed",
    "description": "Pipes Output",
    "link": "http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=b4cac2fb1f1930eb8efce1812b69d5ab",
    "pubDate": "Mon, 08 Nov 2010 20:19:22 -0800",
    "generator": "http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/",
    "callback": "",
    "items": [
      {
        "link": "http://www.etsy.com/listing/60872596/large-green-seasons-greetings-gift-tags",
        "y:title": "Large Green Seasons Greetings Gift Tags Set of 6",
        "y:id": {
          "value": "http://www.etsy.com/listing/60872596/large-green-seasons-greetings-gift-tags",
          "permalink": "true"
        },
       "guid": "http://www.etsy.com/listing/60872596/large-green-seasons-greetings-gift-tags",
        "title": "Large Green Seasons Greetings Gift Tags Set of 6",
        "pubDate": "Fri, 05 Nov 2010 08:13:21 -0400",
        "description": "<img src=\"http://ny-image3.etsy.com/il_155x125.189695523.jpg\"/><br />$18.00<br />Set of 6 large, green gift tags each measuring 2 5/8 x 5 1/4 inches.<br /><br />",
        "y:published": {
          "hour": "12",
          "timezone": "UTC",
          "second": "21",
          "month": "11",
          "minute": "13",
          "utime": "1288959201",
          "day": "5",
          "day_of_week": "5",
          "year": "2010"
        }
     },
```

The desired URL is under the description element, and is

img src="http://ny-image3.etsy.com/il_155x125.189695523.jpg"

for this item in the feed.

What would be the most efficient way to display only the image?

Thanks!

Comment: you'll need to show the JSON (or an example of the JSON) you're retreiving, as we have no idea what the data structure is like.

Comment: can you please post entire JSON ? please post atleast  `"items": []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the URL out of the image somehow (cannot say how because I don't know how the json is formatted)

```
var imgurl = data.value.pic.url; //or whatever
```

Then in the html somewhere have a container

```
<div class="imageContainer">
</div>
```

Then use some jquery to append the image to the container div

```
<script>
    $('div.imageContainer').append('<img src="' + imgurl + '"/>');
</script>
```

EDIT:

I see the problem now, the data.value.item[0].description contains an image tag as well as un-needed information (as you mentioned at first). This is actually a little tricky. What you want to do is wrap the value in description in a span or something then run a selector on it to extract the image:

```
<script>
    var crappyData = data.value.item[0].description;
    var lessCrappy = '<span>' + crappyData + '</span>';
    //Now create a jQuery object out of it
    var notCrappy = $(lessCrappy);
    //Now run a selector on the jQuery object to get all images in description
    var jqueryImage = notCrappy.find('img');
    //Now we can append it to the div mentioned earlier
    $('div.imageContainer').append(jqueryImage);
</script>
```

The only tricky thing is that you have to wrap description in something, or jquery will not be able to make sense of it because it is not well-formed html.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Put a fragment of the json data in the question.

Comment: This is the best solution, however, the ton of unneeded info just keeps messing it up.  Going to try to find another data source!